# StackPanel items don't wrap to new lines

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an `ItemsControl` with a `StackPanel` as the `ItemsPanelTemplate` and the items which get displayed inside (the `Button`) are not wrapped to new lines. I've tried adding the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to the `ItemsControl` and play with the options but it doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RecipientsNames}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="btnContact" Click="BtnContact_Click"
                    Width="Auto" Height="14" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0 0 6 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="12" Margin="0 -2 0 -2"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: StackPanel doesn't wrap items. WrapPanel does

Comment: @ASh uniform grid does too, depending on what layout they are after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting your panels mixed up,

- A StackPanel expands infinity in a linear direction.
- a WrapPanel stacks elements until they hit the edge of the visible
  area then starts a new stack under the previous expanding
  perpendicular to the stacking direction
- a UniformGrid sizes itself to fit the entire area and then splits it
  into a set number of rows and columns, so if you set it to 3 columns
  and add 4 items the 4th will appear in column 1 of a second row,

because the uniform grid unlike the WrapPanel this isn't affected by item size i generally find it produces more visually appealing layouts to the wrap panel but does need to be configured to make best use of the available space